# Dua to get foreskin / reverting circumcision

Tags: circumcision

Assalamu Alaikum, I want to get my foreskin back and revert circumcision, I know it is a sunnah but it is not mandatory in Islam, and in todays world it is easy to access hygiene, so it was nonsense that it was cut off me. I have been praying for nearly one month but still no results. I don't want to rush it but I feel like my prayers are not being answered but I started doing salahs also, I know Allah is hearing me and I promised him to clean it properly and not using it for haram things. (Please note that so called "foreskin restoration" only causes more harm and does not help in anyways getting the real foreskin)
It might sound impossible but nothing is impossible for Allah

Is there any Duas that can help me in this specific thing or any Duas to speed up acceptance?

Answer (score 2):

Allah is the almighty creator of the universe

Allah is *not* a genie in a bottle that you get to rub and make a wish.

He may choose to accept your dua, or reject it, or even to grant you something better, as He wishes. Dua is supposed to help us remember that, to recognize that we are always subject to His will.

There is no magic formula to *make* the almighty creator of the universe do what you want, and it is arrogance to think otherwise. We submit to His will, not the other way around.